# Add custom error message after login failed in Windows Logon

Tags: windows, windows-7, policy

I want to Add Custom Error Message after login failed.

**Default Message**

> You can not log on because the logon method you are using is not allowed on this computer. please see your network administrator for more information

**Add Custom Message**

> You can not log on because the logon method you are using is not
>   allowed on this computer. Please Contact your Administrator As Soon As
>   Possible or Call

I only know when adding messages on Windows logon only. Interactive Logon on Security options can adding some text but that's not what I mean

[Logon Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W16Yv.jpg)

Comment: Problem Resolve. Just edit file authui.dll

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem Resolve. Just edit file authui.dll

Comment: Where is the `authui.dll` file located?